# Can I use two authentication methods in Owin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

In my application I use MVC and Web.API.

The MVC portion handles the admin front-end, serving the `cshtml` pages, communication with the back-end, regular authentication using cookies, etc:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

The Web.API one handles the REST requests made by the iOS and Android applications. For that one I want to use token based authentication:

```
var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true, //todo-err: change in prod
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
};

// Token Generation
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

My question is, what do I need to make this work? Regular and token authentication. Will I need to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute for the API controllers?

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your **SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider** needs to be implemented.
Generating a WebAPI project in VS2015 with authentication gives you [**something like this**](https://github.com/aaronpowell/Owin.AuthenticatedTests/blob/master/Owin.AuthenticatedTests/Providers/ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is implemented. I didn't put it here just to save space. My question is related to whether it would work this way with **both** authentication methods (Regular and Web.API). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The article [**Applying Cookie-Stored Sessions With ASP.NET and OpenID Connect 1.0**](https://dzone.com/articles/applying-cookie-stored-sessions-in-web-farms-with) by Kelvin Amorim is very useful for understanding multiple factors for supporting multiple authentication middlewares.

Some main points are:

- Each authentication options middleware should use a different `AuthenticationType` (it is just a string key and there are some defaults to choose from)
- You can set the cookie path and use corresponding MVC *Areas* (see `RouteAreaAttribute`) to control which cookies are used for which requests